4L60E Slinger or not
I have a 2005 4L60E transmission. The output carrier is a 4 pinion but 2 are sticking, so I'm not comfortable reusing it. I have another 4 pinion carrier I can use, but it has the oil slinger. Will it work? Or do I need 1 without the slinger?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
